# Swift 2 to 3 Migration Error Regarding String Concatenation

Tags: swift, string, swift2, swift3, ios10

I have the following code below.

```
let url = "http://websitehere.com/restapi/v1/userlogin?email="+username+"&password="+password+"&deviceid="+deviceid
```

For some reason the compiler won't take it.  Gives me the following error below.

**Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions**

Why won't the old swift2 code work anymore, what is it even talking about here? If it is too complex, how would I fix it and why is it to complex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would always use this format:

```
let url = "http://websitehere.com/restapi/v1/userlogin?email=\(username)&password=\(password)&deviceid=\(deviceid)"
```

Comment: I just figured this out as you posted it, I must be tired :P, thanks! Will accept answer in 10 minutes once it lets me.